# On a Office VBA 2007 MSForms userform, can a group of controls be moved as a complete group..?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, userform, powerpoint

I have an Office 2007 MSForms UserForm with grouped controls (in Word, but this would also apply to Excel and PowerPoint). To be clear, they're not in a "frame" control; rather, I've used the IDE group/ungroup function to group them together.

I'm working on some Form_Resize code, and I would like to move the group *as the complete group*, rather than to move all the controls individually.

Can this be done? I can't find any sort of "control group" object to refer to. I stopped the code in debug mode and checked every item under `Me.*` and `Me.Controls.*`, and I couldn't find anything obvious.

To touch on the frame control again, I did find I could put the controls in a frame with no caption, background, or border, and that seemed to work. But the grouped control function is easier to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really any other solution than the one you suggested yourself. A different approach would be something like adding the controls to an array, and iterate over it, like this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    Dim c As Variant
    For Each c In Array("TextBox1", "TextBox2", "TextBox3")
        With Me.Controls(c)
            .Top = .Top + 50
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Ahhh yes, also an intresting idea. I forgot about control arrays. I've been working in Access 2007 almost exclusively lately, and it doesn't have them. I sort of like this better than the `.Tag` property idea in the other comment, because with this, the control names are visually right there in one place in the `.Array` function. I'll tag this one as the solution.

Comment: @spinjector, just as an idea:-) if you want to assign every `Tag` ID in **one place** you could do it in *`UserForm_Initialize`* within the same loop `For Each c in Array(...)` as in above code and assign e.g. `Me.Controls(c).Tag = "Group1"`

Answer (score 1):

**Using the `Tag` property of controls to assign an ID**

Maybe it's an easier approach for you to assign an ID to the `Tag` property of all your controls you want to move, e.g. "Group1". So you could use the following code to get the whole *"Family"*.

**Code example**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
' Purpose: move every control with Tag property "Group1"
Dim c As Variant
For Each c In Me.Controls
    If c.Tag = "Group1" Then c.Top = .Top + 50
Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm, nice. Interesting idea. Sort of halfway between a control group and a frame.